How to run this terraform nested for loop?
I've been trying to make this work, but just can't figure it out.
Can you please help?
It should iterate over the private and public route, but also over the cidr_blocks for each type of route.
locals {
  routes = {
    private = {
      route_table_ids  = module.vpc.private_route_table_ids
      cidr_blocks      = ["10.1.0.0/16", "10.2.0.0/16", "10.5.0.0/16"]
    }
    public = {
      route_table_ids  = module.vpc.public_route_table_ids
      cidr_blocks      = ["10.1.0.0/16", "10.2.0.0/16", "10.5.0.0/16"]
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_route" "vpc_route" {
  for_each = {
    for route in local.routes :
      for cidr in route.cidr_blocks : "${route}-${cidr}" => {
        route_table_id         = route.route_table_ids
        destination_cidr_block = cidr
      }
  }

  route_table_id         = each.value.route_table_id
  destination_cidr_block = each.value.destination_cidr_block
  gateway_id             = module.vpc.vgw_id
}

The error I get here is:
╷
│ Error: Invalid 'for' expression
│ 
│   on routes.tf line 17, in resource "aws_route" "vpc_meta_route":
│   15:   for_each = {
│   16:     for route in local.routes :
│   17:       for cidr in route.cidr_blocks : "${route}-${cidr}" => {
│   18:         route_table_id         = route.route_table_ids
│   19:         destination_cidr_block = cidr
│   20:       }
│   21:   }
│ 
│ Key expression is required when building an object.
╵
╷
│ Error: Invalid 'for' expression
│ 
│   on routes.tf line 17, in resource "aws_route" "vpc_meta_route":
│   15:   for_each = {
│   16:     for route in local.routes :
│   17:       for cidr in route.cidr_blocks : "${route}-${cidr}" => {
│ 
│ Extra characters after the end of the 'for' expression.
╵
FAIL


So each of the route table IDs should have all the CIDR blocks? Or it should map 1:1, i.e, one CIDR block to one route table ID?

It should be one CIDR block per route. Example route_private-1:"10.1.0.0/16",  route_private-2:"10.2.0.0/16, ...

I ended up changing it to this, which worked fine.
locals {
  route_table_ids = concat(module.vpc.private_route_table_ids, module.vpc.public_route_table_ids)
  cidr_blocks     = ["10.1.0.0/16", "10.2.0.0/16", "10.5.0.0/16"]
}

resource "aws_route" "vpc_meta_route" {
  for_each = {
    for pair in setproduct(local.route_table_ids, local.cidr_blocks) :
    "${pair[0]}-${pair[1]}" => {
      route_table_id         = pair[0]
      destination_cidr_block = pair[1]
    }
  }

  route_table_id         = each.value.route_table_id
  destination_cidr_block = each.value.destination_cidr_block
  gateway_id             = module.vpc.vgw_id
}


You are missing the key expression from your for expression.
When you are building an object, the syntax requires: key => value
For example: {for s in var.list : s => upper(s)}
Maybe you want to created an array instead? If so change the surrounding brackets.
for_each = [
  for route in local.routes :
    for cidr in route.cidr_blocks : "${route}-${cidr}" => {
      route_table_id         = route.route_table_ids
      destination_cidr_block = cidr
    }
]

Or add the key value
for_each = {
  for route in local.routes : route =>
    for cidr in route.cidr_blocks : "${route}-${cidr}" => {
      route_table_id         = route.route_table_ids
      destination_cidr_block = cidr
    }
}


Both return an exception in the second "for" expression: "Extra characters after the end of the 'for' expression."
Could it be the way I'm declaring the locals?

The for keyword must always appear after either an opening bracket [ or opening brace {, depending on whether you are intending to construct a tuple-typed result or an object-typed result.
That remains true when you use a for expression as the result of another containing for expression; your expression is a syntax error because the for keyword immediately follows the colon of the outer for expression.
Since your inner for expression includes both a key result and a value result (using the => separator), I assume you intended the inner for expression to generate an object too, in which case you'd surround it with braces like this:
  {
    for route in local.routes : {
      for cidr in route.cidr_blocks : "${route}-${cidr}" => {
        route_table_id         = route.route_table_ids
        destination_cidr_block = cidr
      }
    }
  }

However, the outer for expression is still invalid because it's using braces but doesn't use the => symbol to specify both an attribute name and value for each resulting attribute.
Since you're using this in for_each I imagine your goal was to construct a flat map of objects, which means you need an extra step to turn this two-level nested structure into a flattened structure. There are a few different ways to do that but the one that's most similar to what you already tried is to use brackets [] for the outer expression -- producing a tuple of objects with nested objects -- and then discard the outer tuple using the merge function to merge all of the tuple elements together into a single object:
  for_each = merge([
    for route in local.routes : {
      for cidr in route.cidr_blocks : "${route}-${cidr}" => {
        route_table_id         = route.route_table_ids
        destination_cidr_block = cidr
      }
    }
  ]...)

This also uses the ... symbol to use the tuple elements as variadic arguments, so this behaves as if you passed each element of the tuple as a separate argument to merge, which then matches what that function is expecting.
There are a few different moving parts working together to produce this result, so it might be helpful to first try the different parts in an artificial way as the result of an output value, so you can understand exactly what each of the different steps is producing so that you'll be able to recombine these building blocks in different combinations in future. In particular I suggest that you observe what the result is without merge, to understand what exactly that merging step is doing.
